# customized Doughnut char using charjs

Tags: php, yii2, chart.js

I am using yii2 [charjs](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-chartjs-widget) but not able to customize the **Doughnut** chart.

Moreover i have tried [options](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html) from the given document.

```
<?php echo ChartJs::widget([
        'type' => 'pie',
        'data' => [
            'labels' => ["test","test1","test2","Test4"],


            'datasets' => [
                [
                    'label' => 'level',
                    'data' => [10,20,30,40],
                    'backgroundColor' => "blue",

                ],

            ],
        ],
        'options' => [
            'height' => 200,
            'width' => 500,
        ],
]);?>
```

something like this

[image]
Here how can i set separate color for every parts test, test1, test2, test3 respectively **green**,**yellow**,**blue** and **red** ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add colors for each label in datasets

```
'datasets'=> [{
             'label' => 'level',
             'data' => [10,20,30,40],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)', // green
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)', // yellow
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', // blue
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', // red

            ], 
        }]
```

Check this link for more options http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

Answer (score 2):

you should add  the cooresponding color

```
  'datasets' => [
            [
                'label' => 'level',
                'data' => [10,20,30,40],
                'backgroundColor' => ["green", "yellow","blue" ,"red"],

            ],
```